# How to make an SSR build for angular to be served from .NET core webapi properly?

Tags: asp.net-core, build, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, kestrel

I hope I could make things clear about this topic :
I have an Angular + .Net core project 
If I apply the command:
**ng build --prod** 
It would create the static files required to be served by kestrel in wwwroot folder.

And *it would work just fine...*
this is the wwwroot files output:
[wwwroot content files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeoc8.png)

[image: wwwroot content files]

However, If I applied SSR on the angular project and entered the command to build:

**NPM run build:ssr**

I would get the 1 javascript file in the folder wwwroot which is **main.js**

of course when I run

 **dotnet run**

 would get this output from the app 
statusCode: 500,
message: "Could not find file 'C:....\api\wwwroot\index.html'.....

So is this a wrong way of doing it?

 guidance is very much appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Tell us which document you refer to, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm refereeing to angular build for SSR in which I set the command output to be in the .NET api folder wwwroot to be served by kestrel. but the command  npm run build:ssr wont generate the static files needed to run the web app like what the command
ng build --prod does